# Use regex filter at mussy string in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have these kind of strings that I get from my mongo collection:

```
"{\"Id\":\"4573358d-8cac-44a4-85e0-2343wres4321\",\"CreationDateTime\":\"\\/Date(1477834196111)\\/\",\"DeviceId\":\"\",\"UserId\":\"b9cdd9d3-4ac8-4f95-8s44-1234wre44321\",\"UserFullName\":\"groot\",\"SystemId\":\"monitoring\",\"SystemTitle\":\"monitoring\",\"EventId\":\"monitoring.events.udutyallcalculates\",\"EventTitle\":\"xxxx\",\"EventData\":[{\"Key\":\"LogID\",\"Value\":\"\",\"Children\":null},{\"Key\":\"SessionId\",\"Value\":\"GUID\",\"Children\":null},{\"Key\":\"Version\",\"Value\":\"Host- Version=1111\",\"Children\":null}],\"BusinessCode\":\"2-10-102606-46-1-0-0\",\"ProcessId\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\",\"WorkItemId\":ttt,\"WKT\":\"\"}"
```

before query I have to declare a **filter** because I want that kind of information that **BusinessCode** started with **1-**.
Now I am writing this filter :

```
filters.Add(Builders<Message>.Filter.Where(x => x.Payload.Contains("BusinessCode\":\"" + area + "-")));
```

this filter return BusinessCode that start with 1.

12 and other integer that started with 1 are contains.I want to use regex but how could I use this command?
I have written this :

```
filters.Add(Builders<Message>.Filter.Regex(x => x.Payload.Contains("BusinessCode\":\"" + area + "-"), "/^" + area + "/-"));
```

but when I do query from my collection :

```
"var messages = GetDbMongo().GetCollection<Message>(DB_COLLECTION_MESSAGES)
                .Find(Builders<Message>.Filter.Or(filters)).Sort(sort).Limit(count <= 0 ? 10 : count).ToList();"
```

I got this error:

```
Unable to determine the serialization information for x => Convert(x.Payload.Contains((("BusinessCode":"" + Convert(value(Notifications.Common.DAL+<>c__DisplayClass30_0).area)) + "-"))).
```

area = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `Builders<Message>.Filter.Regex` incorrectly, you only need to pass the expression to the property and the regex you want to use:

```
var codeRegex = @"1[^\""]*";
var regex = $@"\\""BusinessCode\\"":\\\""{codeRegex}\\""";

Builders<Message>.Filter.Regex(x => x.Payload, regex)
```

Comment: can you explain about `var regex = \"BusinessCode\\\\\":\\\\\\\"2-10-102606-46-1-0-0\\\\\"";` ?

Comment: I want to this`2-10-102606-46-1-0-0` start with 1. what change i have to do?

Comment: That's just the regex we're matching on, I've updated the example to inject in the "code"

Comment: `12-10-102606-46-1-0-0` is not constant. actually there are a lot of BusinessCode with different values at other documents. and I want to just filter BusinessCode that start with 1 for example. this 1 receive from client .it can be other nubmer

Comment: Just change around the code to be a regex as well... see example now, it will match a code starting with 1 and anything after it

Comment: I have tested your code but it  return this `4-8-104607-27-1-1-0` and 12-11-112395-7-1-0-0 BusinessCode.

Comment: `4-8-104607-27-1-1-0 ` won't match but `12-11-112395-7-1-0-0 ` will as it starts with `1` make a regex here - https://regex101.com/ and replace `codeRegex` with the regex that you choose

Comment: I have changed to this: `var regex = "\\\"BusinessCode\\\":\\\"" + area + "-";` and then `var builder = Builders<Message>.Filter.Regex(x => x.Payload, regex);` and finally its worked.thank you dude.